# What is the downloader option --restrict-filenames for python youtube-dl

Tags: python, macos, youtube-dl

Hello all I was wondering what the option is for the python based version of `youtube-dl` for this argument in terminal `--restrict-filenames`? What does the options in python does the tuple need to have added to it?

Thanks in advance, Ondeckshooting

Comment: This is more appropriate for [su], as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation, that option does not require an argument. So a command
such as this will suffice:

```
youtube-dl --restrict-filenames 73VCKpU9ZnA
```

Here is the option detail:

> Restrict filenames to only ASCII characters, and avoid "&" and spaces in
>   filenames

As far as what ASCII is, this script will reveal:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  while (z++ < 0x7e) {
    $0 = sprintf("%c", z)
    if (/[[:graph:]]/) printf $0
  }
}
```

Result

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Comment: I was looking for the python keyword argument. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: It's [`restrictfilenames`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/d3d89c325681b1f2d9dcc8d8dea3439aad570f1f/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L139).